# Windows 10 user accounts getting mixed up

Tags: windows

I have a Windows 10 machine that has two local user accounts, will call them User1 and User2, and one Administrator Account.
Recently there has been a strange behavior with the user accounts where they will copy each other's background and account images.
User1 and User2 both have unique wallpapers and user images but if I log on to User1 and then log off and log on to User2 there is a random chance that the account image from User1 will have replaced the account image for User2.
If I go to "Settings->Accounts->Your Info" I will see both the original account image and the one from User1 that replaced it side by side. The image seems to get copied from

```
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures
```

and pasted to

```
C:\Users\User2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures
```

This happens in both directions where User2's image gets itself over to User1. It has also happened on occasion with wallpapers being swapped over.
Neither of these accounts are listed on each other's security tab so one shouldn't have even read access to the other's folders.
Has anyone else seen this sort of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I've discovered the reason for the behavior that I described above. Both User1 and User2 have Windows Live accounts. I logged into the XBox app on User2 in order to change the settings so that the controller home button doesn't interfere with Steam. As a result the same Windows Live account became associated with both local accounts on the machine. What I was seeing wasn't information copied from one account to another but Windows trying to sync the accounts thinking that they were the same user.

I went into User2 and used that user's Live account to log into the XBox app and then went to "Settings->Accounts->Email & app accounts" under "Accounts used by other apps" and removed my Live account from User2 so that only User2's information was present. This seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: I figured that was the issue, but you figured it out first. Well done. You should be able to mark this as the answer once the time period expires.